# Calling an instance of a non-related class in python

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how to call an instance of a random class but with code like this, it throws:

> app.classAFunction is not defined

```
class ClassA():
    def __init__(self):
        b = ClassB()

    def classAFunction(self):
        print("classAFunction was succesfully called")

class ClassB():
    def __init__(self):
        app.classAFunction()

app = ClassA()
```

Can you explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: in ClassB init method, `app` is not declared. instantiate it from there, not in global scope

Comment: so I would have to do self.app = app ?

Comment: rather `self.app = ClassA()`

Comment: Ok, but wouldn't that cause a new instance of the ClassA to be created?

Comment: What is this code even supposed to do? `app` is a `ClassA` instance, which instantiates a `ClassB` instance, which calls a method on `app` even though nothing is bound to that name yet? Wut? This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: We can explain why the posted code doesn't work, but we can't tell you how to fix it unless you describe what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `ClassA` inits `ClassB` it can pass itself to `ClassB` like:

```
class ClassA():
    def __init__(self):
        b = ClassB(self)

    def classAFunction(self):
        print("classAFunction was succesfully called")

class ClassB():
    def __init__(self, class_a_app):
        self.app = class_a_app
        self.app.classAFunction()

app = ClassA()
```

Comment: This works, but what if b is created not in the ClassA initializer, but in an instance method of that class instead? Should I provide an example code to illustrate this question?

Comment: You should **always** provide code to illustrate.  I thought you already had. Please edit your question

Comment: Your answer was sufficient for me to be able to get past the issue. Actually the whole problem culminated with me coming to understanding that I didn't use lambda when applying event to a button in tkinter. Thank you.